# psycopg2 no error but not inserted into DB

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm using the class below, and I can successfully retrieve data using the "getAccount" method, but the "insertToken" method does not insert the data. I've tried the SQL manually and it does work. I also don't get any errors. Any idea what is wrong here?

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

class Database:
    variable = "blah"

    def getAccount(self):
        accountId = 0;
        username = ""
        password = ""
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='token_generator' user='token_generator' host='myip' password='mypass'")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            try:
                cur.execute("""SELECT id, username, password from account where used = false limit 1""")
            except Exception as e: print(e)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                accountId = row[0]
                username = row[1]
                password = row[2]
        except:
            print("I am unable to connect to the database")
        return (accountId, username, password)


    def insertToken(self, token, accountId):
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='token_generator' user='token_generator' host='myip' password='mypass'")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            try:
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO token (token, account_id) VALUES (%s, %s)", (token, accountId))
            except Exception as e: print(e)
        except:
            print("I am unable to connect to the database")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you doing `conn.commit()` after the insert to commit the transaction? Also you'll need `cur.close()` `conn.close()` at some point to close things cleanly.

You can also use `autocommit` mode. And as the comment by Jared points out it would be cleaner to use a context manager in stead of `try/catch`.

```
with psycopg2.connect("dbname='token_generator' user='token_generator' host='myip' password='mypass'") as conn:
    conn.autocommit = True
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        try:
            cur.execute("INSERT ...")
        except Exception as exc:
            print("Error executing SQL: %s"%exc)
```

Comment: Context manager omits the need for `close`ing. Tag did say python3.

Comment: conn.commit() fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM token_generator.pg_stat_activity
```

should give you a list of recent queries.

If the query you think you're running works manually, then you're most likely not running the query you think you're running. This should help you figure out which query you're actually running, and then make changes accordingly.